# Where are PHP errors logged to if the error_log directive simply says "error_log"?

Tags: php, error-log

I ran `phpinfo()` and the *error_log* directive simply says `error_log`. What file is that referring to? i.e. what would the full path to the *error_log* be?

Comment: The canonical is *[Where does PHP store the error log? (PHP 5, Apache, FastCGI, and cPanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/)* (despite the over-specific title).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the value simply says `error_log` (or `error_log = error_log` in your `php.ini` file), that means the errors will be written to a file called `error_log` in the same directory that the error occurs.

So, if you have a file called `index.php` in */home/user/public_html/* that throws an error, the error will be written to: */home/user/public_html/error_log*.

If you have file called `resize.php` in */home/user/public_html/admin/images/* that throws an error, then the errors will be written to: */home/user/public_html/admin/images/error_log*

---

*Source: [Display and log errors for PHP](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php-troubleshooting/troubleshoot-php-errors)*

Comment: It is probably not wise to keep error_log = error_log, because you don't want random people reading your error_log by visiting your website foobar.com/admin/images/error_log. this is a security concern. (unless you set your server settings to not serve error_log files, however)

Answer (score 16):

Quote [from the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log):

> error_log string
>
> Name of the file where script errors should be
>   logged. The file should be writable by the web server's user. If the
>   special value syslog is used, the errors are sent to the system logger
>   instead. On Unix, this means syslog(3) and on Windows NT it means the
>   event log. The system logger is not supported on Windows 95. See also:
>   syslog(). If this directive is not set, errors are sent to the SAPI
>   error logger. For example, it is an error log in Apache or stderr in
>   CLI.

So, when the value is not set (which is the default) it will be sent to the parent error logger, which is apache (if run via it) or `stderr` if you run the script on the command line.

If you use the script via apache you will have to look at the apache error log, usually in `/var/log/apache` or `/var/log/httpd`, depending on your distribution. You can check the apache configuration file for the exact location.

**Edit:**

I just noticed I misread your question, I guess you mean `error_log` has the actual value `error_log`?

I just did some testing. When I set `error_log` to a value like `php_errors.log` PHP still writes the error messages to the apache error log. It behaves as if the value was empty. When I set the value to a full path (e.g. `/tmp/php_errors.log`) then it writes the errors to the specified file.

So I guess in your case it writes the errors to the apache error log file.

Of course you can set your own log file be adding

```
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php_errors.log");
```

to your PHP files where you need it (if it hasn't been disabled by an administrator).

Comment: there's no `/apache` in `/var/log`. but there is an `error_log` in `/usr/local/apache/logs` but it doesn't seem to show any PHP errors. when i run my PHP page I'm getting a blank screen and i want to know the syntax error. `display_errors` is turned off in `php.ini`.

Comment: you should be able to turn on `display_errors` in your php file itself. Just add `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the beginning.

Comment: I believe that `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` tells PHP to echo error messages to the screen via the output HTML.

Comment: Another location is `/var/log/apache2` (extra "2") (observed on a [fairly standard LAMP installation](https://www.osradar.com/install-lamp-ubuntu-20-04/) on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa))).

Comment: in php.ini check APACHE_LOG_DIR

Answer (score 0):

Open your *php.ini* file.

Check the path against *error_log*.

Comment: This should not have gotten downvoted, because this is proper usage as intended. People should use the tools provided the way they were intended and only spin their own solution up if it is inaccessible or not supplied. There's too many people on this site that assume that just because it didn't solve their specific issue (and all of it's related but unreported issues) that it's automatically wrong. This is not wrong, and if it doesn't work, then your server is set up poorly, which is your real problem.

Comment: I would add though that logs can also be defined in the apache.conf or vhost.conf as well.

Comment: I agree with voting this down for the simple reason that it doesn't explain anything clearly.

Comment: What do you mean *"Check the path against error_log."* (seems incomprehensible)? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23286129/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

On [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10), [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) 10.0.18362.1, I set this in file `php\php.ini`:

```
error_log = "C:\tmp\php_errors.log"
```

or

```
error_log = C:\tmp\php_errors.log
```

or

```
error_log = \tmp\php_errors.log
```

[phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) shows:

> error_log    C:\tmp\php_errors.log or  \tmp\php_errors.log

Sometimes directly, but always after `iisreset` (recycling the application pool).

That is where the file is saved.

Without pad: `error_log = php_errors.log` it will be written where the error occurs. It has already been mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Without pad"*? Can you elaborate?